# How do I change file/folder permissions from cpanel?

Tags: joomla, permissions, cpanel

I have a joomla website, which I recently moved and I'm having problems with file permissions. The easy fix would be to change all the folders and files permission to 0777, do whatever I need to do, and then change them back. I don't think that's possible anyway - to change them all at once then make everything as it was.

The other solution would be to switch permissions to user Apache from cpanel. Can I do that? How? What other options do I have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out that you can't change the owner from the cpanel. My solution was to contact my hosting and have me transferred to another server of theirs that used FastCGI, which made all my files' owner Apache (instead of null, or nobody, what it was before).

I couldn't find my answer on the internet, I had to ask them and they gave me that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file/folder permission using the **cpanel**.

1. Just login to your cpanel,
2. there you can find a option called "File Manager".
3. Just click on that, it will list all your files and folders in a table at the window.

   In the table, at the last column which will be named as "Perms". Just click on the column corresponding to the file/folder for which you want to change the permission.

Comment: I didn't want to change permission, I wanted to change the owner.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old thread, but may useful for next user come here.

There is good tool for doing this by Jacob, here you can visit his page http://boomshadow.net/tech/fixes/fixperms-script/, but may you need root access to do it.